# How to prove this using Taylor's Theorem

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

If $g(x)= \sin x$, prove that the remainder of the Taylor's Theorem converges to zero when $n \to \infty$, for each $x_0$ and $x$ fixed.

My thoughts so long:

By the Taylor's Theorem and given fixed $x_0$ and $x$ we have:

$P_n(c)=\sin(x_0)+\cos(x_0)(x-x_0)-\frac{\sin(x_0)}{2!}(x-x_0)^2-\frac{\cos(x_0)}{3!}(x-x_0)^3...$

The remainder is $R_n(c)= \frac{\sin^{n+1} (c)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}$

But I'm stuck at this expression, does it make sense to take the limit as n approaches infinity of the $R_n$ expression?

Comment: $\sinx$ needs to be fixed to $\sin x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$0\leq\bigg|\frac{\sin^{n+1}c(x-x_0)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\bigg|\leq \bigg|\frac{(x-x_0)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\bigg|.\tag{1}$$

Let $a_n= \frac{(x-x_0)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$,then $$\lim\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(x-x_0)^{n+2}\cdot(n+1)!}{(n+2)!\cdot(x-x_0)^{n+1}}=0$$
So $\sum a_n$ converges by ratio test, then $\lim a_n=0$.

Therefore the rightmost side of $(1)$ tends to zero.
Then by SQUEEZE theorem middle part of $(1)$ also tends to $0$.

Comment: Thanks, but why is that truth?

Comment: Where does that inequality come from? Is it from definition of limit of a sequence?

Comment: $-1\leq \sin x\leq 1$ from this $|\sin x|\leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't understand you manipulate that equation of $\sin x$ to get to the expression in your answer, and what do you mean that the RHS tends to zero by Ratio test?

Comment: I modified my answer , hopefully you'll be able to understand now. If you don't know ratio test then google it.@MarioM21

Answer (score 1):

You're not really limiting in a continuous way but rather as discrete sequence of terms. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence)

Comment: Thanks, I know it's the limit of a sequence, but how to compute it?

Comment: Usually you wannt manipulate into something where you can apply the limit without the blow up (just for evaluating the limit) but after that proving the limit is another task

Comment: Oh it's true, do i need to compute the limit before proving it? And to prove it, can it be by definition?

Comment: Proving and computing are different thing.

Comment: Proving is much harder than computing [seehere](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-series-new/bc-series-optional/v/proving-a-sequence-converges)

Comment: Yes I know, but in this case can I prove it without computing it?

Comment: Basically you first compute the limit and then you formally prove that the quantity you got is what the limit converges too. You can't really do a proof without knowing what the limit you are trying to prove is

Comment: Maybe I find by calculation that limit becomes say some quantity x , then I need to proving using the limit definitions that it becomes x

Unless I found x , I will not know what to prove that sequence becomes